# Typecasting int pointer to float pointer

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I'm trying to do the following

```
int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

printf("%f\n", *(float *)a);
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+1));
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+2));
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+3));
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+4));
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+5));
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+6));
printf("%f\n", *((float *)a+7));
```

I get

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

The reason why I'm trying to print the elements in this way is because, I want to cast the int pointer to the array to the float pointer and pass it as a parameter for another function which only takes `float *`.

It seems that this does not work well. Can someone explain why this is not working?

```
int *ptr;
function((float *)ptr);
```

If I do this the function does not read the values the pointer is pointing to properly.. just returning `0.0000`.

Comment: What is your the expected value?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not correct. `int` and `float` are not guaranteed to have the same alignment.

Remember: Casting a value and casting a pointer are different scenarios. Casting a pointer changes the *way* to refer to the *type* value, which can *almost certainly* result in a mis-alignment in *most* of the cases.

As per `C11` standard document, chapter **§6.3.2.3**

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned<sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

In your case, a *work-around* may be

```
printf("%f\n", (float)*a);  //cast the value, not the pointer
```

Comment: The question is asked for C, not C++

Comment: @infiniteloop If I am not in an urgent need to book a visit to an ophthalmologist, I don't see any mention of CPP in my answer and I believe I don't need to book a visit either. clarification, please?

Comment: Sincere apologies @Sourav. I overlooked it.

Comment: @infiniteloop never mind, and I believe we all have a little space for humor, hope I did not offend you either, right?

Comment: No not at all :), that was my mistake. Between on `gcc 4.8.5 - 64bit`, where size of int and float are 4 bytes, when I tried to convert int value to float through `float *` as above, store it in float and again back to another int variable. I could get the actual data. According to my observation, `printf()` in C could not actually print very low values of int (I mean to say 4 byte value stored as an integer not float), so it is printing `0`. Increasing the value of int and gives a correct result.

Comment: According to my observation, printf() in C could not actually print very low values of int *as float*(I mean to say 4 byte value stored as an integer not float), so it is printing `0.000000`. Increasing the value of int,gives a correct result (I mean float value corresponding to int value, i.e., int of 10 doesn't gives 10.000000, rather it gives value depending on method used to implement float in the compiler).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot *cast* a pointer to `int` to a pointer to `float`, and expect to get your value converted to the corresponding number in floating point representation. Casting a single value works, but casting by changing a pointer type does not alter the representation.

If you need an array of `float`s, declare an array of `float`s, and cast one element at a time:

```
float b[8];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
func_expects_float(b, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting an int pointer to a float doesn't convert the integer to a floating point number. Casting just tells the machine to use the contents of the memory location pointed to by the pointer as floating point value instead of an integer value. But it doesn't change the value from integer representation to floating point representation.

Answer (score 0):

you might try:

```
printf( "%f\n", 1.0f * a[0]); 
printf( "%f\n", 1.0f * a[1]); 
....
```

==or==

```
printf( "%f\n", *(a+0) * 1.0f ); 
printf( "%f\n", *(a+1) * 1.0f ); 
....
```